# Ansible: Does the `hosts: all` pattern in a play only match hosts specified in inventory, or does it also match playbook `add_host` hosts?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I know "all" doesn't match the implicit localhost; the title succinctly expresses my question.

Motivation: I have a playbook that needs to be run on cloud hosts generated dynamically and added to groups with `add_host` during a playbook, but I also need to run the whole playbook on a vagrant vm, as well as in CI (molecule), so I want to use "all" for the latter two cases, so that when I specify inventory, certain plays will target the inventoried hosts.  These plays will also have the names of the add_host groups, so that I don't have to duplicate plays.  I'm just wondering if I can write

`hosts: all` # instead of

`hosts: all:group1:group1...`

for these plays, and have the `add_host` hosts included, without specifying their names.  I will only specify inventory for the vagrant and molecule scenarios, and not for the live cloud deployment scenario, so that I don't target my entire cloud infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: *"**Does the `hosts: all` pattern only match hosts specified in inventory, or does it also match `add_host` hosts?**"*

A: Simple test shows `hosts: all` includes also added hosts by `add_host`. In the same playbook, of course. The dynamic groups live inside a playbook only.

Given the inventory

```sh
shell> cat hosts
host1
host2
```

The playbook

```yaml
---
- name: Only 2 hosts in the inventory
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts_all
      run_once: true

- name: Add host3 to the group1
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: host3
        groups: group1
      run_once: true

- name: All 3 hosts are available to this play
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts_all
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [Only 2 hosts in the inventory] **************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - host1
  - host2

PLAY [Add host3 to the group3] ********************************************

TASK [add_host] ***********************************************************
changed: [host1]

PLAY [All 3 hosts are available to this play] *****************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************
ok: [host3] => 
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - host3
  - host1
  - host2
```